# functional fields in openerp - convert amount to word string

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to know how can we convert an amount in to equivalent amount string in `opnerp7`.
I defined a functional field to achieve this but its creating a field in my DataBase but not the data , can anyone please point out where am i wrong, I can post my sample source here

**View:**

```
<field name="amount_words"/>
```

**python code**

**function that returns converted amount -**

```
def _amount_in_words(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):

    cur_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
    res = {}
    for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        taxed = untaxed = 0.0
        res[order.id] = {
            'amount_words': '0.0',
                        }
        val = val1 = 0.0
        cur = order.pricelist_id.currency_id
        for line in order.order_line:
            val1 += line.price_subtotal
            val += self._amount_line_tax(cr, uid, line, context=context)

        taxed = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val)
        untaxed = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val1)

        res[order.id]['amount_words'] = amount_to_text(float(taxed + untaxed))

    return res[order.id]['amount_words']
```

**functional field declaration**

```
'amount_words': fields.function(_amount_in_words, string='In Words', type="char", store=True, help="The amount in words"),
```

**Note :**- 'amount_to_text' is a my applications global function that is giving exactly what I want but I could't pass the same data in to my view ???

'amount_to_text' returns data like as follows , if I pass amount_to_text(150) it returns 
One Hundred and Fifty rupees Only

Answer (score 0):

When you are storing a functional field you need to provide a trigger so the ORM layer knows when it should recalculate and store your field.  However, that is mostly meant for the situation where you have a functional field that depends on values from another model and you want to speed up OpenERP by not having it calculate the amount each time the value is displayed.

A classic use case is invoices.  The total on an invoice is the sum of the lines so to speed things up there is a triggered functional field so that whenever the invoice lines change, the total is recalculated and stored on the invoice.  Have a look at the account.invoice or sale.order models in the certified modules (OpenERP addons).

In your case it makes more sense to over-ride the write method and test if any of the required fields are in the values dictionary, and if so, calculate and store the amount in words.

For example (from memory here so apologies in advance):

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, values, context = None):
    if 'quantity' in values or 'price_unit' in values:
        values['amount_in_words'] = _get_amount_in_words(....)

    return super(MyClass, self).write(cr, uid, ids, values, context = context)
```

A couple of points though:

1. You will have to adjust the "if field in values" test to include
   every dependent field.  It may be better to just remove this and do
   it every time.
2. Don't forget to override the create method as well.
3. Remember the old adage "early optimisation is the root of all evil".
   Are you really sure you need to persist the amount in words?

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your explanation , and also pointing out a future risk of saving / retrieving amount in words.